# iTunes podcast get feed url

Tags: rss, itunes, podcast

I am trying to get feed url from iTunes podcast, for example  https://podcasts.apple.com/us/channel/lemonada/id6442462434

```
    var url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup'

    var params = 'id='+id+'&entity=podcast';

    xhrRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhrRequest.readyState == 4) {

        
            console.log(xhrRequest.responseText)
        }
    }
    xhrRequest.onerror = function(e) { 
       
    };
    xhrRequest.open('POST', url);
    xhrRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhrRequest.send(params);
```

But I get empty results, like:

```
{resultCount: 0, results: Array(0)}
```

I want to get feed url so I can parse podcast rss.

Comment: This link you have is for a channel. A channel in Apple Podcasts is a collection of one too many shows. You need to find the link to the show you want then use the API with the show ID.

Comment: How do you find a link to individual show?

Comment: Nothing you can do via API - it would just manually grabbing each of the 32 shows URLs from the app. Here is an example of one of those shows: https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/funny-cuz-its-true-with-elyse-myers/id1645926587